# Multiple If answers before Else statement? (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

I am making a calculator and would like to know if its possible to have multiple IF answers before running the ELSE command

My current code is this

```
echo 1 - Addition
echo 2 - Subtraction
echo 3 - Multiplication
echo 4 - Division
echo 5 - Exit
set /p startans=Type 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 then press ENTER: 
if %startans%==1 goto :addition
if %startans%==2 goto :subtraction
if %startans%==3 goto :multiplication
if %startans%==4 goto :division
if %startans%==5 goto :end
```

However if you type something other than those numbers it will take you straight to addition because that comes next in the file. How do I make an ELSE command work for all 5 answers?

Comment: Place a `goto :eof` or `goto :inputerror` after the last `if`. You might be interested in [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are interpreted line by line. So to implement an else-branch you've to add a goto statement right after your last if-statement:

```
if %startans%==5 goto :end
goto :wrong_input

rem all of your other jump marks here

:wrong_input
echo Your input is not valid
```

Another way would be to use the alternative IF-syntax where you can nest IF conditions:

```
IF "%startans%" == 1 (
    REM addition code here
) ELSE (
    IF "%startans%" == 2 (
        REM Subtraction here
    ) ELSE (
        REM neither addition nor subtraction code here
        echo Your input is not valid
    )
)
```